# rich:calendar : Icon hidden by an other component

Tags: jsf, richfaces

How can I keep icon shown for `rich:calendar` component?

I need to add another `rich:calendar` component, but the `outputLabel` hide the icon.

[image: Screen Shot]

Code (edited) :

```
                        <h:panelGrid columns="4" styleClass="criteresSaisie"
                            rowClasses="critereLigne"
                            columnClasses="titreColonne,,titreCourtColonne,">
                            <h:outputLabel for="dateDeb" value="Période du" />
                            <rich:calendar id="dateDeb" inputSize="8"
                                value="#{criteresDecRgltBacking.dtDebDecRglt}"
                                enableManualInput="true" datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                showInput="true" converterMessage="la date de début doit être au format dd/MM/yyyy">
                                <rich:validator/>
                            </rich:calendar>
                            <h:outputLabel for="dateFin" value="au" style="margin-left:20px;"/>
                            <rich:calendar id="dateFin" inputSize="8"
                                value="#{criteresDecRgltBacking.dtFinDecRglt}"
                                enableManualInput="true" datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                showInput="true" converterMessage="la date de fin doit être au format dd/MM/yyyy" >
                                <rich:validator/> 
                            </rich:calendar>
                            <f:event type="postValidate"
                                listener="#{rechercheDecRgltCtrl.validationPeriode}" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
```

CSS

```
div.rf-ac-itm {
height: auto !important;
overflow: visible;
}


div.rf-ac-itm-cnt {
height: auto !important;
overflow: visible;
}

.critereLigneAugmente td {
padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.espaceVideCalendar {
width: 10px;
}
.espaceVide {
width: 20px;
}

.espaceColonne {
width: 30px;
}

.titreColonne {
text-align: right;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 180px;
}

.titreCourtColonne {
text-align: right;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 40px;
}

.titreColonne .libelle,.titreColonne label {
padding-right: 10px;
}

.titreColonne .libelle label {
padding-right: 0px;
}

.largeurFixeCriteres{
width: 120px;
overflow: visible;
}
.criteresSaisie {
margin: 10px;
}
.largeurFixeCriteresTiers {
width: 120px;
overflow: visible;
}
.critereLigneAugmente td {
padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.finDeLigne {
width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the view code related to this section?

Comment: Use a `margin` as it's most probably a pure CSS issue.

Comment: @skuntsel I tried to use `margin-right` but I have the same problem!

Comment: I've tested your view code, removing only EL codes on JSF 2.1 with RichFaces 4.X and everything is fine

Comment: Open the rendered view in Firebug and play with CSS around the needed area to get understanding on what is to be changed.

Comment: There is something bad in `titreColonne` or `titreCourtColonne`.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I'll tray to test CSS :)

Comment: @Netmaster you should post these CSS classes!

Comment: Have you tried using this CSS: `margin-left: 10px` (or another value)?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie I'll modify the post

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I tried to insert margin, but I got the same problem in chrome (it works for firefox and ie)

Comment: With the code, no problem in FF 22.0, Chrome 27.0 an IE 8.0. Doctype problem?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I could see that have a chance to cause problem is the classes order in `columnClasses` that was `"titreColonne,,,titreCourtColonne,,"` and you changed now to `"titreColonne,,titreCourtColonne,"`.

Previously you where trying to apply a 40px width on a `rich:calendar` column (**titreCourtColonne** was on the second `rich:calendar` column instead of the **au** column).

I recommand to change this CSS for better styling :

```
.titreCourtColonne {
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 20px;
}
```